# Assistance needed with calculating value of pi using java

Tags: java, pi

Question That Needs To Be Solved: http://i62.tinypic.com/23rtieb.png

I have this problem I need to solve using Java. However I tried but was not able to. Here is what I have done so far.

```
public class Cirlce {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int counter = 0;
        double pi = 0;
        final String piCharacter = "\u03C0";
        double num = 10000;
        int e = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {

            // r^2 = x^2 + y^2
            double dx = Math.random();
            double dy = Math.random();
            double r = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);

            if (r < 1) {
                counter++;
                pi = 4 * counter / 1000;
            }
            e++;
            if (e == counter) {

                System.out.println(pi);
                counter += 1000;
            }


            System.out.println("The Approximated Value Of " + piCharacter + " is: " + pi);
        }
    }
}
```

The answer is that I need 10 outputs that are close to the value of pi.

Comment: Note that your `if(e==counter)` is only going to return true a handful of times, then never return true again.  I would actually recommend using nested loops here - an outer one where the index goes from 0 to 9, and an inner one where the index goes from 0 to 999.  You should print out your estimate of pi at the end of each iteration of the outer loop.

Comment: Can you show me how you would solve this problem?

Comment: `counter` is being used to count the number of hits inside the circle, but it is also erroneously being used to try to match every 1000th loop iteration. `e` is being incremented every time around the loop, making it a virtual duplicate of `i`, the loop variable. What a mess.

Comment: Zero, I explained how I would solve the problem.  I hope you're not asking me for actual code.

Comment: Thank You For The Help, I Think I Got What Question Was Asking.

Answer (score 2):

One problem is in this line:

```
pi = 4 * counter / 1000;
```

`4`, `counter` and `1000` are all `int`, so you are doing integer arithmetic here. You'll need to make at least one of the values a `double`, for example:

```
pi = 4.0 * counter / 1000;
```

There are some other errors. For example, why are you doing `counter += 1000;`? Cleanup your code and make sure you understand exactly what each statement does.

Comment: Could you please show me how you would do the problem ?

Comment: Zero - Stack Overflow is not a "do my homework for free" site.

Comment: The only reason why I was asking was because I'm new to Java and need some extra help.